# Webpack error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to webpack and react and am trying to set up an application. From looking at previous questions I think there must be something wrong with how I am setting up babel-loader, but I'm unable to see what my mistake is. Is anyone else able to see it?

webpack.config.js:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'waves/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'waves/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: [
  {
     test: /\.jsx?/,
     include: APP_DIR,
     loaders: ["babel-loader"],
     query: {
       presets: ['es2015', 'react']
     }
  }
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

babel.rc

```js
{
 "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Index.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {

 render() {
  return <p>Hello React!</p>;
 }
}

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for the module options object: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module

If you have `babel-preset-2015` and `babel-preset-react` npm modules installed and the following `webpack.config.js` (`babel.rc` file isn't needed with the query presets) should work:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'waves/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'waves/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      include: APP_DIR,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you webpack file to include the babel-loader within quotes and included in an array of loaders as shown below. In modules you define an array of loaders to handle different types of files but a single loader for a particular type.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'waves/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'waves/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
   module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```